# Android resize container with animation

Tags: android, animation

I have a linear layout with a couple text boxes, vertical.  I want to add/remove one more text box (more specifically, set it to visible/gone).  When this happens, I'd like to resize the parent view with an animation rather than just having it jump up and down.  I've put a layout animation on the parent linear layout, and it animates the box in/out, but it appears to resize first, then animate the child, but that doesn't really solve the problem I'm having (looks nice, but you know).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this question is pretty old, but I thought this would be a common problem before I run into it myself.

I took some inspiration from the code you had, but instead of using a separate class like this, what I did is to extend the LinearLayout class and added some methods to be able to animate it when the content changes (in my case, I am making some children views VISIBLE or GONE). Still working out a few details, but it works pretty well so far.

The good thing is that I can access / extend onMeasure method, so I do not have to do any estimation of the size after the animation, no matter what I have in my container, the animation will always go to the right place.

Hope that helps

Comment: picked your answer.  Not sure which is better/worse, but if its a toss up, its kind of lame to pick your own ;)

Answer (score 1):

I figured something out.  I do it the "hard way" by resizing the container.  The basic process is as follows:

Save the layout parameters
Get the physical size of the container
Set the layoutparams with the physical height
Loop with a handler setting the size incrementally
When its done, set the previous layout params

The code assume you're using a linear layout and a height of WRAP_CONTENT.  If not, it would need an adjustment.

See blog

http://www.touchtech.co/blog/resize-animation/